# Php code results not matching mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

mySQL Table

> ID | Name
>
> 1 | A
>
> 2 | B
>
> 3 | C
>
> 4 | D
>
> 5 | E

mySQL Query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ego_work WHERE 1;
$result = mysql_query($query);

$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

php Code

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $work): ?>
     <span> <?php echo $work['id']; ?>, </span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<br \>
<?php foreach ($rows as $work): ?>
     <span> <?php echo $work['name']; ?>, </span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

RESULT

> 1,2,3,4,5
>
> E,A,B,C,D

What did I do wrong? I'm trying to get the 2nd result to be A,B,C,D,E

Comment: Could you post the result of a `var_dump` on `$rows`? I suspect your table's data aren't what you think they are.

Answer (score 1):

can you try below code

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $work): ?>
<span> <?php echo $work['id']; ?>, </span>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php reset($rows);?>
<br \>
<?php foreach ($rows as $work): ?>
 <span> <?php echo $work['name']; ?>, </span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```